# how to use a prebuilt toolchain for cortex m3

Tags: cortex-m, gnu-toolchain, uclinux

I have downloaded following gnu toolchain for cortex m3 and unzipped it but i don't understand how to use it   -> http://www.codesourcery.com/sgpp/lite/arm/portal/package6503/public/arm-uclinuxeabi/arm-2010q1-189-arm-uclinuxeabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu.tar.bz2

my computer has windows 7 ,is it necessary to have linux as host computer ??

Comment: linux is not required there are cross compilers for windows or linux or mac using llvm or gcc.  your question is too vague what part do you not understand?  what board/chip do you have and what have you tried so far?

Comment: The toolchain build you have downloaded is intended to run only on Linux.  If you want to do bare-metal Cortex M3 development there are certainly versions available that run on Windows.  There may be versions that run on windows and target uClinux on your platform, but things start to get a bit more complicated there and you may want to seriously consider moving your development work to a Linux environment.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience doing development for embedded Linux works best with a Linux host. Depending on what you want to achieve you might get along with a Windows host, but it is not the best way.